# Typescript module paths for Node.js in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2017

MSVC 2017 sets up node's type definitions in Scripts/typings/node. When I install socet.io along with types it wants to pick up types for node from @types/node (which seems like a reasonable place) and installs the @types/node as a dependency.

This causes all sorts of drama in the project. So I changed the /// reference path for the socket.io index.d.ts to point to Scripts/typings/node and this works. (btw... how do you specify a relative path for a reference path I can't figure it out. The system seems to always mangle the path I want to use).

Is there a way of getting visual studio to pick up node typings from the node_modules/@types directory and not Scripts/typings/node?

Cheers
O.

Comment: The docs explains this at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html under "@types, typeRoots and types".

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case for Visual Studio. It uses a project file (which is a hot mess) instead. I like the IDE but I think this is a bit of a problem this it's difficult to find any online guides for working with the *.njsproj files.

Comment: Starting from later versions of VisualStudio 2015 the tsconfig.json file was honored higher than the csproj. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3124 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5287